# Jacobian matrix of function and bases

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations

> Let $V,W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over the field
> $\mathbb{k}$ and assume that $\mathcal{A}:V\to W$ is a linear map. If
> we fix bases $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{m}$ in $V$ and $\{f_j\}_{j=1}^n$ in $W$,
> then $\mathcal{A}$ is defined by a unique matrix $A$. Taking different
> bases $\{e'_i\}_{i=1}^{m}$ in $V$ and $\{f'_j\}_{j=1}^n$ in $W$, we
> obtain the different matrix $A'$. It is easy to find the relation
> between matrices $A$ and $A'$.

Let's take a look at the definition of differentiable function with many variables.

> Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be an open set. We say that $f:E\to
>  \mathbb{R}^n$ is **differentiable at** $x\in E$ if there is linear map
> $L(x):\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and a function
> $\alpha:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
> $$f(x+h)-f(x)=L(x)h+\alpha(h)\lVert h\rVert$$ holds at some deleted
> neightborhood of $0\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\lim\limits_{h\to
>  0}\alpha(h)=0$. That linear map $L(x):\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is
> called differential of $f$ at $x$ and is denoted as $df(x)$ or
> $f'(x)$.

One can perform some computations and show that $df(x)$ is defined by the following matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    \partial_1f^1(x) & \partial_2f^1(x) &  \dots  & \partial_mf^1(x) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \partial_1f^n(x) & \partial_2f^n(x) &  \dots  & \partial_mf^n(x)
\end{pmatrix},$$
which is called Jacobian matrix.

I remember how this matrix was derived but I am asking myself the following

**Question.** For which bases in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and in $\mathbb{R}^n$ this matrix is derived? May be for standard bases in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$? I don't remember that this basis fact have been used in the computing of Jacobian matrix.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes: the Jacobian of $f$ at $x$ is the matrix of $df(x)$ relative to the **standard bases** of $\Bbb R^m$ and $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, Thank you for your reply! But I am still confused where do we use the fact that these bases are standard? If you can post a detailed answer to my question I'll highly appreciate it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard derivation of the Jacobian, there is no *need* to consider the particular basis of the domain and codomain under consideration. So, the literal answer to "where do we use the fact that these bases are standard" is "nowhere".

I think that your implicit question is the following: given bases $\mathcal B_1 = \{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$ of $\Bbb R^m$ and $\mathcal B_2 = \{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ of $\Bbb R^n$, how would we compute the matrix of $df(x)$ relative to these bases? With that, it is easy to say why it is that the standard basis yields the Jacobian matrix.

When discussing the entries of a matrix, it is convenient to introduce *dual bases*. We say that a set $\mathcal B_2^* = \{\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n\}$ of linear functions $\beta_i:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is the *dual basis* to $\mathcal B_2$ if we have
$$
\beta_i(w_j) = \begin{cases}
1 & i=j\\
0 & i \neq j.
\end{cases}
$$
The role of the dual basis is to extract the individual components of a vector in $\Bbb R^n$ corresponding to the elements of $\mathcal B_2$. In other words, if $w = x_1 w_1 + \cdots + x_n w_n$, then $\beta_i(w) = x_i$ (for $i = 1,\dots,n$).

For a linear map $L:\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$, the $i,j$ entry of the matrix $[L]^{\mathcal B_1}_{\mathcal B_2}$ (of $L$ relative to the bases $\mathcal B_1, \mathcal B_2$) is given by $\beta_i(L(v_j)).$

Note that the [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) of $f$ along the vector $v$ is given by the limit
$$
D_vf(x) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x + tv) - f(x)}{t}
$$
Usually, when this concept is introduced $f$ is necessarily scalar valued and $v$ is necessarily a unit vector, but this need not hold in our case. From your definition, we are given that
$$
f(x+h) - f(x) = df(x)h + o(\|h\|),
$$
So the above limit becomes
$$
D_vf(x) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x + tv) - f(x)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac {tdf(x)(v) - o(t)}{t} = df(x)(v).
$$
With that stated, the $i,j$ entry $m_{ij}$ of $M = [df(x)]^{\mathcal B_1}_{\mathcal B_2}$ is given by
$$
m_{ij} = \beta_i(df(x)(v_j)) = \beta_i[D_{v_j}f(x)]
$$
So, what's special about the standard bases? If we take $\mathcal B_1$ to be the standard basis, then the directional derivative $D_{v_j}f(x)$ is simply the **partial derivative** of $f$ with respect to $x_j$. That is, we have
$$
m_{ij} = \beta_i[D_{v_j}f(x)] = \beta_i[\partial_j f].
$$
If we then take $\mathcal B_2$ to be the standard basis, then the dual basis $\mathcal B_2^*$ is simply the set of component functions $\beta_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \beta_i$. That is, we have
$$
m_{ij} = \beta_i[\partial_j f] = \partial_j f^i.
$$
So, when $\mathcal B_1,\mathcal B_2$ are the standard bases, then $[df(x)]_{\mathcal B_2}^{\mathcal B_1}$ is the Jacobian matrix of $f$.

---

An alternative approach: as we established above, the $i,j$ entry of the matrix $M = [df(x)]^{\mathcal B_1}_{\mathcal B_2}$ is given by
$$
m_{ij} = \beta_i(df(x)(v_j)) = (\beta_i \circ df(x))(v_j).
$$
In the case where $\mathcal B_2$ is the standard basis, the dual basis elements are simply the standard projection functions $\beta_i = \pi^i$ (as you correctly note in your comment below). I claim that
$$
\pi^i \circ df(x) = df^i(x).
$$
To show that this is the case, we can show that $df^i(x)$ satisfies the requirement from your definition:
$$
(\pi^i \circ f)(x + h) - (\pi^i \circ f)(x) = 
f^i(x + h) - f^i(x) = df^i(x)(h) + o(\|h\|).
$$
From there, we have
$$
m_{ij} = (\beta_i \circ df(x))(v_j) = df^i(x)(v_j).
$$
Now, we can note that for any scalar-valued function $g$, $dg(x)(v)$ is simply the directional derivative of $g$ along $v$. Indeed, we note that
$$
D_vg(x) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{g(x + tv) - g(x)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac {tdg(x)(v) + o(t)}{t} = dg(x)(v).
$$
Now, if $\mathcal B_1 = \{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$, then we have
\begin{align}
m_{ij} &= df^i(x)(e_j) = D_{e_j}f^i = \partial_j f^i.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank a lot for posting an answer! A few typoes: **1)** "In other words, if $w = x_1 w_1 + \cdots + x_n w_n$, then $\beta_i(w) = x_i$ (for $i = 1,\dots,n$)." **2)** For a linear map $L:\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$, the $i,j$ entry of the matrix $[L]^{\mathcal B_1}_{\mathcal B_2}$ (of $L$ relative to the bases $\mathcal B_1, \mathcal B_2$) is given by $\beta_i(L(v_j)).$

Comment: @ZFR Fixed the typos. If you're satisfied with my answer, please "accept" it by clicking the check mark ($\checkmark$) on my post

Comment: I read your answer and it actually perfectly answers my question! I am deeply satisfied with your answer! May I ask you one more question regarding your answer since I am little confused? When we take $\mathcal{B}_2$ to be the stancdard basis $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$, then in that case $\beta_i$ is just projections $\pi^i$. Then we have that $m_{ij}=\pi^i[\partial_j f]$ and you write that it is equal to $\partial_j f^i$. It seems a bit weird because partial derivative is defined for real-valued functions but here $f:E\to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $E\subset \mathbb{R}^m$. Did you get my point?

Comment: @ZFR Partial derivatives are also defined (if you prefer, they *can* also be defined) for vector-valued functions. $\partial_j f$ is simply the directional derivative of $f$ along the $j$th standard basis vector.

Comment: But as far as I know in the definitions of directional derivative (in particular, in the definition of partial derivatives functions supposed to be real-valued). Now I am confused. I mean at least in the book which I am reading functions supposed to be scalar.

Comment: @ZFR Again, what I am using is a slightly more general definition. If you want to avoid this, you can instead write
$$
\beta_i(df(x)(v_j)) = (\beta_i \circ df(x))(v_j),
$$
show that $\beta_i \circ df(x)$ is the transposed gradient of $f^i$, then consider $$
(\beta_i \circ df(x))(v_j) = (\nabla f^i)^T v_j.
$$

Comment: Excuse me! The first equality is just the definition of composition. After that it is not clear at all. Can we stick to the regular definition of partial derivatives? I am wondering can you explain that in your answer please? I understood literally everything but this last sentence in your answer. It would be great if you can change that last sentence a bit please.

Comment: @ZFR See my edit

Comment: When you are trying to show that $\pi^i\circ df(x)=df^i(x)$ you do some computations after that and they show that $d(\pi^i\circ f)(x)=df^i(x)$ but the LHS is actually $d\pi^i(f(x))\circ df(x)$. However, one can check that $d\pi^i(x)=\pi^i$ because it does not depend on $x$. Hence $df^i(x)=\pi^i\circ df(x)$, right?

Comment: @ZFR I have no idea what you mean by "but the LHS (left hand side) is actually $d\pi^i(f(x)) \circ df(x)$". Yes, it's true that $d\pi^i(x) = \pi^i$, and with that you can also prove that $d(\pi^i \circ f)(x) = \pi^i \circ df(x)$ using the chain rule; I'm not sure if this is what you have in mind with what you wrote, though

Comment: It is exactly what I meant. Sorry for confusing phrasing! Such an excellent answer! It helped me to understand my question and connections between some other ideas. Thank you so much!